# how to apply multiprocessing logic on a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a function to be applied on a dataframe it takes more time to execute so i want to try multiprocessing in that function

```
import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())

def some_function_you_want_executed_in_parallel(args):
   pass  # logic goes here

arg_list = []  # put input arguments here

results = pool.map(some_function_you_want_executed_in_parallel, arg_list)





PLAA_Scripts2['ClaimUnitsWithRespite_CA_CUWR'] = PLAA_Scripts2.apply(lambda x :\
    fsScripts_getClaimUnitsWithRespite_Inline1(EndDate,\
    x['BeginDate_SC'],x['EndDate_SC'],x['AuthorizationID_SC'],False),axis=1,result_type='reduce')
```

i have to apply the above multiprocessing logic to the fsScripts_getClaimUnitsWithRespite_Inline1 function with with values from columns of the dataframe PLAA_Scripts2.

how to apply the multiprocessing logic to this function

Comment: What does the function do? Applying custom functions is a fall-back approach

Comment: With the little information you provided us, as roganjosh said, you could find another approach using pandas built-ins instead of apply. If you really need apply and your DataFrame is still too big, I think you could divide it in chunks, and apply a multiprocessing from there.

Comment: @roganjosh the function goes row by row in the PLAA_Scripts2  dataframe and returns a single value where arguments are from the columns of PLAA_Scripts2 dataframe